# T900 Skype Virus How to detect and how to remove

Tags: attacks, virus, trojan, information-gathering

I hope that this is the correct forum to post this question. I wanted ask what is the best way to identify if a machine is infected with the virus T9000 and also, which antivirus programs are capable of detecting T9000 if it exists on a machine, and capable of removing it as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal forum